# How to change TextBox input language to Persian as you type in

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a website in which users should fill some fields in different languages.
I don't want the users to change their writing language using Alt+Shift key combination but rather i want the input language to be changed automatically to either Persian or English.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
if (typeof HTMLElement!="undefined" && ! HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentElement) {    
HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentElement = function (where,parsedNode) {
    switch (where) {
        case 'beforeBegin':
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(parsedNode,this)
            break;
        case 'afterBegin':
            this.insertBefore(parsedNode,this.firstChild);
            break;
        case 'beforeEnd':
            this.appendChild(parsedNode);
            break;
        case 'afterEnd':
            if (this.nextSibling)
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(parsedNode,this.nextSibling);
            else
                this.parentNode.appendChild(parsedNode);
            break;
    }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentHTML = function (where,htmlStr) {
    var r = this.ownerDocument.createRange();
    r.setStartBefore(this);
    var parsedHTML = r.createContextualFragment(htmlStr);
    this.insertAdjacentElement(where,parsedHTML)
}

HTMLElement.prototype.insertAdjacentText = function (where,txtStr) {
    var parsedText = document.createTextNode(txtStr)
    this.insertAdjacentElement(where,parsedText)
}
}

var FarsiType = {
// Farsi keyboard map based on Iran Popular Keyboard Layout
farsiKey: [
    32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 1548,   1711,
    41, 40, 215,    43, 1608,   45, 46, 47,
    48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
    56, 57, 58, 1705,   44, 61, 46, 1567,
    64, 1616,   1584,   125,    1609,   1615,   1609,   1604,
    1570,   247,    1600,   1548,   47, 8217,   1583,   215,
    1563,   1614,   1569,   1613,   1601,   8216,   123,    1611,
    1618,   1573,   126,    1580,   1688,   1670,   94, 95,
    1662,   1588,   1584,   1586,   1740,   1579,   1576,   1604,
    1575,   1607,   1578,   1606,   1605,   1574,   1583,   1582,
    1581,   1590,   1602,   1587,   1601,   1593,   1585,   1589,
    1591,   1594,   1592,   60, 124,    62, 1617
],
Type: true,
counter: 0,
ShowChangeLangButton: 1,    // 0: Hidden / 1: Visible
KeyBoardError: 0,           // 0: Disable FarsiType / 1: Show Error
ChangeDir: 2,           // 0: No Action / 1: Do Rtl-Ltr / 2: Rtl-Ltr button
UnSupportedAction: 0        //0: Disable FarsiType / 1: Low Support
}

FarsiType.enable_disable = function(Dis) {
var invis, obj;

if (!Dis.checked)  {
    FarsiType.Type = true;
    disable = false;
    color = 'darkblue';
} else {
    FarsiType.Type = false;
    disable = true;
    color = '#ECE9D8';
}

if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
    for (var i=1; i<= FarsiType.counter; i++) {
        obj = document.getElementById('FarsiType_button_' + i);
        obj.disabled = disable;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
}

FarsiType.Disable = function() {
FarsiType.Type = false;
var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
if (Dis != null) {
    Dis.checked = true;
}

if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
    for (var i=1; i<= FarsiType.counter; i++) {
        obj = document.getElementById('FarsiType_button_' + i);
        obj.disabled = true;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = '#ECE9D8';
    }
}
}

FarsiType.init = function() {

var Inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for (var i=0; i<Inputs.length; i++) {
    if (Inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text' && (Inputs[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa' || Inputs[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa-ir')) {
        FarsiType.counter++;
        new FarsiType.KeyObject(Inputs[i], FarsiType.counter);
    }
}

var Areas = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA');
for (var i=0; i<Areas.length; i++) {
    if (Areas[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa' || Areas[i].lang.toLowerCase() == 'fa-ir') {
        FarsiType.counter++;
        new FarsiType.KeyObject(Areas[i], FarsiType.counter);
    }
}

var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
if (Dis != null) {
    FarsiType.enable_disable (Dis);
    Dis.onclick = new Function( "FarsiType.enable_disable (this);" )
}
}

FarsiType.KeyObject = function(z,x) {

GenerateStr = "";
if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) {
    GenerateStr = GenerateStr + "<input type='button' id=FarsiType_button_"+x+" style='border: none; background-color:darkblue; font-size:11; color:white; font-family:tahoma; padding: 1px; margin: 1px; width: auto; height: auto;' value='FA' />&nbsp;";
}
if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) {
    GenerateStr = GenerateStr  + "<input type='button' id=FarsiType_ChangeDir_"+x+" style='border: none; background-color:darkblue; font-size:11; color:white; font-family:tahoma; padding: 1px; margin: 1px; width: auto; height: auto;' value='RTL' />"
}
z.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", GenerateStr);

if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
    z.bottelm = document.getElementById ('FarsiType_button_' + x);
    z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to english';
}
if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) {
    z.Direlm = document.getElementById ('FarsiType_ChangeDir_' + x); 
}

z.farsi = true;
z.dir = "rtl";
z.align = "right";

z.style.textAlign = z.align;
z.style.direction = z.dir;

setSelectionRange = function(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    input.focus()
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
}

ChangeDirection = function() {
    if (z.dir == "rtl") {
        z.dir = "ltr";
        z.align = "left";
        z.Direlm.value = "LTR";
        z.Direlm.title = "Change direction: Right to Left"
    } else {
        z.dir = "rtl";
        z.align = "right";
        z.Direlm.value = "RTL";
        z.Direlm.title = "Change direction: Left to Right"
    }
    z.style.textAlign = z.align;
    z.style.direction = z.dir;
    z.focus();
}

ChangeLang = function(e, ze) {
    if(ze)
        z = ze;

    if (FarsiType.Type) {
        if (z.farsi) {
            z.farsi = false;
            if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
                z.bottelm.value = "EN";
                z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to persian';
            }
            if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 1) {
                z.style.textAlign = "left";
                z.style.direction = "ltr";
            }
        } else {
            z.farsi = true;
            if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { 
                z.bottelm.value = "FA";
                z.bottelm.title = 'Change lang to english';
            }
            if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 1) {
                z.style.textAlign = "right";
                z.style.direction = "rtl";
            }
        }
        z.focus();
    }
    
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

Convert = function(e) {

    if (e == null)
        e = window.event;

    var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    var eElement = e.target || e.originalTarget || e.srcElement;

    if (e.ctrlKey && key == 32) {
        ChangeLang(e, z);
    }

    if (FarsiType.Type) {
        if (
            (e.charCode != null && e.charCode != key) ||
            (e.which != null && e.which != key) ||
            (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) ||
            (key == 13 || key == 27 || key == 8)
        ) return true;

        //check windows lang
        if (key > 128) {
            if (FarsiType.KeyBoardError == 0) {
                FarsiType.Disable();
            } else {
                alert("Please change your windows language to English");
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If Farsi
        if (FarsiType.Type && z.farsi) {

            //check CpasLock
            if ((key >= 65 && key <= 90&& !e.shiftKey) || (key >= 97 && key <= 122 ) && e.shiftKey) {
                alert("Caps Lock is On. To prevent entering farsi incorrectly, you should press Caps Lock to turn it off.");
                return false;
            }

            // Shift-space -> ZWNJ
            if (key == 32 && e.shiftKey)
                key = 8204;
            else
                key = FarsiType.farsiKey[key-32];

            key = typeof key == 'string' ? key : String.fromCharCode(key);

            // to farsi
            try {
            
                var docSelection = document.selection;
                var selectionStart = eElement.selectionStart;
                var selectionEnd = eElement.selectionEnd;

                if (typeof selectionStart == 'number') { 
                    //FOR W3C STANDARD BROWSERS
                    var nScrollTop = eElement.scrollTop;
                    var nScrollLeft = eElement.scrollLeft;
                    var nScrollWidth = eElement.scrollWidth;

                    eElement.value = eElement.value.substring(0, selectionStart) + key + eElement.value.substring(selectionEnd);
                    setSelectionRange(eElement, selectionStart + key.length, selectionStart + key.length);
    
                    var nW = eElement.scrollWidth - nScrollWidth;
                    if (eElement.scrollTop == 0) { eElement.scrollTop = nScrollTop }
                } else if (docSelection) {
                    var nRange = docSelection.createRange();
                    nRange.text = key;
                    nRange.setEndPoint('StartToEnd', nRange);
                    nRange.select();
                }

            } catch(error) {
                try {
                    // IE
                    e.keyCode = key
                } catch(error) {
                    try {
                        // OLD GECKO
                        e.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, true, false, 0, key, eElement);
                    } catch(error) {
                        //OTHERWISE
                        if (FarsiType.UnSupportedAction == 0) {
                            alert('Sorry! no FarsiType support')
                            FarsiType.Disable();
                            var Dis = document.getElementById('disableFarsiType')
                            if (Dis != null) {
                                Dis.disabled = true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            eElement.value += key;                  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.preventDefault)
                e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (FarsiType.ShowChangeLangButton == 1) { z.bottelm.onmouseup = ChangeLang; }
if (FarsiType.ChangeDir == 2) { z.Direlm.onmouseup = ChangeDirection; }
z.onkeypress = Convert;
}

if (window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent('onload', FarsiType.init)
} else if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', FarsiType.init, false)
}
```

Now all you have to do is to create a text box and set its Lang attribute to "fa-IR".

```
<input type="textbox" name="text1" Lang="fa-IR" />
```

or

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="Server" Lang="fa-IR" />
```

Load your page and it's done!

Comment: Hello @Ali Rashidi i have try with your code and also it's work on text box but below of the textbox button also generate automatically so can you please know how can it's fix and remove this button.?

Comment: Rashidi can you please know any other wave for that task acatully i am not used for that perticular one new js so any other wave then please let me know.

Comment: it can be use for change to english language too? how? `Lang="en-US"`?

Comment: Hello Ali what if  write in input tag with mix of English and person which the sort of that become unclear to read?