# To change the keyboard typing language to the specific field in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to make the automatically language switching to fill a form in two different language  without swithcing the language of keyboard manually from windows setting?

Comment: Please be specific. Do you want to change the language display on you CI pages? or you want to change the input characters to a different language?

Comment: To change the input characters to different language

Comment: Dude can't do that on codeigniter.

Comment: I'm searching for the solution that might do this using javascript???Can we do this using javascript??

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041312/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-to-persian-as-you-type-in

Comment: I want the japnaese language js file, but i couldn't find it on the internet