# change keyboard input language for some fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I'm trying to build a web form that contains user's name textfields for the user to enter his/her name in three different languages, let's say English, Arabic, and Hebrew.

I want to make the keyboard input method to change when the focus goes from one textfield to the other according to its correspondence supposed language.

Can I do this with javascript? Any experience in this area?

Thanks

Comment: I don't nearly have the appropriate setup to investigate this, but did you try setting specific [lang](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes) attributes on these elements?

Comment: I don't think so :/ maybe with custom external support using external file like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041312/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-to-persian-as-you-type-in
But I want something generic and ready to use for multiple languages :(