# Change input language according to user specified language

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to type into the language specified by the user according to the language selected. I got the following URL for the same but it supports only Farsi.

[Change input to Farsi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041312/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-to-persian-as-you-type-in).

Please can anyone suggest me how to get this done or are there any online sources by which the languages be converted to js files to be referred ?