# Reactjs change keyboard language auto to persian

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in reactjs.some of the inputs must fill in persian but without using ALT+SHIFT keys. I found some code in javascript and i have tried [How to change TextBox input language to Persian as you type in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041312/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-to-persian-as-you-type-in). but its not working.
can anybody help me that how can i change my keyboard language in reactjs?
or is there any way to mapping chrecters in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add `lang` attribute to your input using jquery or hard coded:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("input#NameTextBox").attr("lang", "fa");
});
```

In addition to above code you also need to add the reference to `farsitype` a library to handle the language in your `head` tag.

```
<script language="javascript" src="FarsiType.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

More info [here](http://www.farsitype.ir/).