# How to change TextBox input language to locally default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic-languages

Follwing [How to switch input to other language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041312/how-to-change-textbox-input-language-to-persian-as-you-type-in), lets say I want to change the input language to Hebrew or location based language.
By changing I want that any keyboard text that will be typed in `input` element will appear in the language I set on it(without a user action like `alt+ctrl`).

Is there a `JS` or angular lib for it?
It does not have to be dynamic, even hardcode for start will be great, like:

```
<input type="textbox" name="text1" Lang="fa-IR" /> //persian
```

In this case all user `input` inserted appear in persian.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is:
1/ Retrieve user's language preference
2/ then update the `Lang` attribute of your input accordingly

I suggest you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38150585/3410584 for the 1/ and then you can do

```
var language = yourFunctionToRetrieveUserLanguage();
var input = document.getElementsByName('text1')[0];
input.setAttribute('Lang', language);
```

;

Comment: The lang attribute does not change the keyboard language(like I want).